# location services not working after Enabling - Disabling - Enabling

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

My app uses location services. While testing my application i found an issues with location services. If I start my application with location services enabled on the phone, i am getting GeoLocationStatus.Ready status and then i press the start button and navigate to settings and disable location services the application gets a GeoLocationStatus.Disabled status.Then if I press the start button, navigate to settings and enable location services and then return to the app, I still get GeoLocationStatus.Disabled. From this point on I will always get GeoLocationStatus.Disabled until I restart the application with location services enabled.

I have observed this issue on Windows Phone 7.5 OS ( Samsung Focus & HTC HD7)

There is no issue with same app on Windows Phone 8 OS (Nokia Lumia 920)win